# Laravel creates a new session on every request

Tags: php, laravel, session

for some reason that I can't figure out my Laravel install has started created a new session file on every request! This renders the session useless and so I users can't stay logged in, csrf tokens don't match etc.

I'm using Laravel 5.2. It seems fine on my local environment but not on the live server

Does anyone have any clues on why this might have happened and how I can resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running some caching server? Varnish, nginx proxy caching, etc?

Comment: are you using the authentication by default of Laravel 5?

Comment: PHP 5.2 is too old. consider upgrading to at least to PHP >= 5.5.9 (as it's said in requirements of Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation#server-requirements)

Comment: Sorry, meant Laravel 5.2! My mistake

Answer (score 8):

Locally everything worked, but not on the production server. The problem was in the **php.ini** settings on the hosting, by default the parameter (variable) "**mbstring.func_overload = 2**" was set there. I removed it and than all worked. This parameter is for previous versions (PHP) which is used by many CMS. And Laravel gave an error 419 during authorization and nothing more, and created a new session every time the page was updated.

Comment: you saved my day. how did you find that?

Answer (score 5):

after the upgrade from 5.1 to laravel 5.4 I had a similar issue,
I found that I didn't upgraded app/Http/Kernel.php correctly.

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
```

was declared twice in `protected $middleware` array
and in

```
protected $middlewareGroups
```

after removing it from `$middleware` array
it started to work correctly

`$middleware` applied to all routes
and `$middlewareGroups` applied to specific groups

Comment: I have this exact same issuer on Laravel 8 - this fixed it

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I was testing locally on the subdomain of the production site.

My local Laravel was at `dev.example.com` (mapped to localhost), and prod was at `example.com`. Prod cookies interfered with the development site.

Solution: clear interfering cookies OR move dev site away from subdomain.

Comment: Same problem... I changed sub domains when I branched my project, and didn't update the APP_URL variable in the .env file. A day lost ***facepalm***

Answer (score 1):

Check [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13000) - there's a change in Laravel 5.2.27 that automatically registers the web middleware for you, so if you manually use it in your routes (which you had to in 5.2) then it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be quirk of PHP + MacOS. It was a blank line before `<?php` in our index file. Absolutely ridiculous issue with hours lost on debugging.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked this thread [laravel forum](http://laravel.io/forum/07-15-2015-new-session-is-created-on-each-request)

its says to check if there is any blank line before the `<?php` tag in the file
app/config/app.php , if any remove the blank line

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this problem and it was caused by using dump().

This was sending output to the browser (just as whitespace before php tags would) and causing my session to break.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this happens a lot when a session can't start because headers have already been sent to the browser (The [session_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) function needs to send out several HTTP headers).

It can be due to a space or newline character before an opening `<?php` tag in any file.

Instead of searching for the culprit, this can be easily solved by enabling PHP's [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering).
Look for the `output_buffering` directive in your **php.ini** and change it to

```php
output_buffering=4096
```

This is the recommended value for production servers anyway and it may already be defined in OP's local env so the session works there as expected.

Comment: Adding new solutions to old questions is nothing to be sorry about.